# PHP Code For Twilio Works In Terminal But Not In Browser

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api

I've got the following php file below. When I run it from the terminal, it works great. However, when I open php file in the browser, I get the following exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException' with message 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Http/CurlClient.php:41 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/AMPPS/www/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Rest/Client.php(208): Twilio\Http\CurlClient->request('POST', 'https://api.twi...', Array, Array, Array, 'AC9fc89840f15b3...', 'd1db324eb375a2e...', NULL) #1 /Applications/AMPPS/www/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Domain.php(70): Twilio\Rest\Client->request('POST', 'https://api.twi...', Array, Array, Array, NULL, NULL, NULL) #2 /Applications/AMPPS/www/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php(64): Twilio\Domain->request('POST', '2010-04-01/Acco...', Array, Array, Array, NULL, NULL, NULL) #3 /Applications/AMPPS/www/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php(216): Twilio\Version->request('POST', '/Accounts/AC9fc...', Array, Array, Array, NULL, NULL, NULL) #4 /Applications/AMPPS/www/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/MessageList.php(70): Twili in /Applications/AMPPS/www/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Http/CurlClient.php on line 41

Here is my code:

```
    <?php // sendMessageTwilio.php

  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  use Twilio\Rest\Client;

    // Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
  $account_sid = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
  $auth_token = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
  // In production, these should be environment variables. E.g.:
  // $auth_token = $_ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]

    // A Twilio number you own with SMS capabilities
  $twilio_number = "+XXXXXXXX";

  $client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
  $client->messages->create(
      // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
      '+XXXXXXXXXXX',
      array(
          'from' => $twilio_number,
          'body' => 'Testing From Website New!'
      )
  );

  $number = $question = '';

  if (isset($_POST['number'])){
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $out = "Number: $number";
  } 

  if (isset($_POST['question'])){
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $out = $out."   Question: $question";
  } 

  else $out = "";

  echo <<<_END

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Student Feedback</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>

      Enter phone number and question
      <b>$out</b>
      <form method="post" action="sendMessageTwilio.php">
        Phone Number: <input type="text" name="number" size="17">
        Question:     <input type="text" name="question" size="17">
                      <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
      </form>
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
_END;
```

I'm using the composer to get all the necessary files set up.

Thanks all!

Comment: If I upload it on the server it also works...so seems to be a local issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux servers usually have the [ca_cert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) in place. Follow these steps to fix your issue

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/235279367-Twilio-PHP-helper-library-SSL-certificate-problem-on-Windows

**UPDATE**

Here is my code

```
$http = new Services_Twilio_TinyHttp(
  'https://api.twilio.com',
   array('curlopts' => array(
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
   ))
);

$sid = 'ACfb185500bf13ce37c37fd2e13dsdfsdf'; 
$token = '4be5dcdb74e4cbd50d642a56b1fasdf2'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, "2010-04-01", $http);

$message = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
    '+441231231231', // From a Twilio number in your account
    '+441231231231,
    'OTP for login is: 1234'
);
```

You need to set curl options to suppress the SSL verification

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
```

Comment: Thanks Ashik! I should have mentioned that I'm on a Mac. I've followed these instructions:

http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/ImportRootCert#Using_the_command_line

But I'm still getting the same issue...

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Thumbs up! For anybody using Laravel framework can disable SSL verification in the Guzzle package